# Having a table of contents in Crystal report or SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

How can I have a table of contents with their related page numbers at the start of a report  in Crystal report or SSRS?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to Crystal Reports, but within SSRS, you can create a Document map.

A Document Map is similar to a Table of Contents, but more flexible to support the different rendering extensions: a page number is not applicable for web pages, and in an Excel export, you are likely more interested in the different tabs instead of pages. Document maps support these.

[Here's one](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jason/archive/2010/05/13/how-to-add-a-document-map-to-your-reports.aspx) of several results from a search on "SSRS Document Map." (I chose to link to this because of the images with an example of document maps, but the MSDN docs are helpful as well.

Comment: thanks. but how can i simulate something like indexes of a book with topics and their related page numbers as a report in a web application. do you know a powerful reporting tools to implement that.

Comment: Document maps can do this to some degree, but the order of the document map will match the order of the report. Also in SSRS you could oragnize your owning paging, forcing page breaks with grouping. Then you could easily create your own index with a tablix of items at the end. The challenge will be to reliably determine what can fit on one page.  I'm more familiar with SSRS than other tools, so I don't have any answers for what other options are available.